# Change system volume using crontab & pactl

Tags: sound, scripts, cron, volume-control

I am trying to change Ubuntu 14.04 system volume using crontab.
I am using following command:

```
pactl set-sink-volume 1 75%
```

Which works fine when I use it in terminal or when I run script which includes this command, but when system runs this code from crontab or via script which runs on crontab, system does not change volume. How can I fix this?

I also have tried

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master 75%
```

Crontab looks like (every minute for testing purpose)

```
* * * * * pactl set-sink-volume 1 75%
```

or

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/pactl set-sink-volume 1 75\%
```

Comment: I think you will have to tell the crontab to connect to your instance of the pulse sound server. I have no idea how to do that or if it's possible but I doubt that cron is the way to go. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you tell us your final objective, we might suggest a better way.

Comment: I think you are missing an environment variable, cron runs with a limited set of -.

Comment: I basically have PC which loops video file (VLC). On day, audio must be turned on, but for night, audio must be turned off.

Comment: Basically I have script (loads on/off time, volume level etc. from remote server), this script checks every minute if it is time to turn on/off projector or alter volume. If it is time to turn off projector, audio must be turned off as well. Also, audio level could be changing turning the day.

Comment: does this script run from cron? a dirty workaround (setting the volume to zero or whatever value, at a defined time) would be easy, but via cron can be tricky.

Comment: Yes, this script runs from cron.

Comment: Silly question, but do you want / need it to run from cron? you prevent some complications if you time it otherwise in these situations (including it in a script)

Answer (score 4):

Took me a while to figure it out, you can do this:

```
1 9 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && amixer -D pulse sset Master 48000

1 22 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && amixer -D pulse sset Master 32000
```

On 100% volume is roughly 64000. That'll get volume up at 9, and down at 22.
Also on your user crontab, not sudo's.

Comment: Better late than never. +1

Comment: @TimeTraveller2100 it doesn't work from me. It just changes the selected audio output. If the Speakers are selected it changes the speakers volume, if the HDMI is selected it changes the HDMI audio outpus. I want it to work witht the sound settings closed and affect the HDMI audio or both of them. How can I do that?

Comment: On a slightly unrelated side note, you can simply declare DISPLAY=:0 on a line by itself in cron and then it will apply to all listed schedules after that, ie:

    DISPLAY=:0
    1 9 * * * amixer -D pulse sset Master 48000
    1 22 * * * amixer -D pulse sset Master 32000

Answer (score 2):

Starting with **Ubuntu 19.10**, a simple `DISPLAY=:0` (or even 0.0) didn't help in cron, I got this error:

```
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

I had to do the following instead (This is my **mute-at-night** cron, but you can adapt to your needs):

```
30 21 * * * bash -l -c "DISPLAY=:0.0 pactl --server unix:/run/user/$(id -u)/pulse/native set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ on"
```

#### Breakdown:

- `bash -l` for login shell.
- `DISPLAY=:0.0` for display
- `--server unix:/run/user/$(id -u)/pulse/native`: (explicit file descriptor since cron isn't in a login shell)
- `@DEFAULT_SINK@ or 0` : The default or first audio device.  For a specific device, you can use the full device name, eg `alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo`
- `on` (or `off`): mute on/off

The piece I had to add in Ubuntu 19.10 was the `--server` arg.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. You can use @DEFAULT_SINK@ instead of 0 in "...set-sink-mute 0 on"

Answer (score 1):

#### Running commands from cron

Works fine and reliable in many occasions, but when you need or want to run for example GUI applications, or in other situations where environment variables are involved, it can be quite a search to find out how to properly setup a (combination of) cron job(s), and to find out *which* environment variables should be set and how.

#### Alternative

In these situations, it can be convenient to have a simple alternative, to run a command at a specific time, or even run a complete "day program", from the current user's environment.

That is what the script below does. It runs commands and/or applications, listed in a text file in a simple format, looking like:

```
11:09,gedit
11:10,gnome-terminal
11:20,pactl set-sink-volume 1 10%
```

I tested it with your command, and it works fine.

#### How to setup

The setup exists of three small files, which you need to store in one and the same folder. In one of these files (`command_data.txt`), you need to list the commands, together with the time you'd like the commands to be executed, that's all.

Use the following format:

```
time/comma/command (no spaces around the comma)
```

to raise the volume in 5 minutes to 100% for example:

```
11:20,pactl set-sink-volume 1 0%
11:21,pactl set-sink-volume 1 20%
11:22,pactl set-sink-volume 1 40%
11:23,pactl set-sink-volume 1 60%
11:24,pactl set-sink-volume 1 80%
11:25,pactl set-sink-volume 1 100%
```

#### The files:

As said: the three files should be located in one and the same folder.

*file 1, the main script.* 
Copy it into an empty file, save it as `schedule.py` (keep the name as it is) and make it executable (important)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import time
import datetime
import os

cmd_data = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"/command_data.txt"

with open(cmd_data) as data:
    s = [item.strip().split(",")+[None] for item in data.readlines()]

def currtime(set_time):
    return int(set_time.split(":")[0])*60+int(set_time.split(":")[1])

def run_command(t, now, cmd, last_run):
    if currtime(t) == now and last_run != int(time.strftime("%d%m%Y"))+int(now):
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
    else:
      pass

while True:
    now = currtime(str(datetime.datetime.now().time())[:5])
    for i in range(len(s)):
        cmdata = s[i]       
        run_command(cmdata[0], now, cmdata[1], cmdata[2])
        s[i][2] = int(time.strftime("%d%m%Y"))+int(now)
    time.sleep(30)
```

*file 2, the script to start/stop the schedule.* 
Save it as `run_schedule.py` (keep the name as it is) and make it executable (important)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess

script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
cmd = "ps -ef | grep schedule.py"
run = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]).decode("utf-8").split("\n")
match = [line for line in run if script_dir+"/"+"schedule.py" in line]

if len(match) != 0:
    subprocess.Popen(["kill", match[0].split()[1]])
    subprocess.Popen(["notify-send", "Schedule stopped..."])
else:
    subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", script_dir+"/"+"schedule.py"])
    subprocess.Popen(["notify-send", "Schedule runs..."])
```

*file 3, create an empty file, named `command_data.txt`* 
fill it with your commands as explained in "How to setup"

start / stop (toggle) the schedule by the command:

```
/path/to/run_schedule.py
```

A notifying message will appear:

[image]   or: [image]

#### Explanation

What the files do:

When the script `schedule.py` is started, it reads the commands and their scheduled running time from `command_data.txt`. In a loop, the current time is compared to the scheduled time of the listed commands. If the current time equals one or more of the scheduled job times, the command is performed and marked as "done" for the current time.

The script `run_schedule.py` checks if the main script (`schedule.py`) is running. If so, the job is killed, if not, the script is started. In both cases a confirming notification is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this. My motion screen/audio now works when PIR gets triggered.

```
import time
import subprocess
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
import os
import logging
import time
import subprocess

os.environ["DISPLAY"] = ":0"

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='output.log', level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')


# Read in value of default_sink.txt for default_sink
with open('default_sink.txt', 'r') as f:
    default_sink = f.read().strip()

print(default_sink)

# Constants
IR_SENSOR_PIN = 4  # GPIO pin number of IR sensor
TIMER_DURATION = 60  # Timer duration in seconds

# Initialize IR sensor and timer
ir_sensor = MotionSensor(IR_SENSOR_PIN)
timer = time.time() + TIMER_DURATION  # Set timer to expire immediately

#run pactl command like this DISPLAY=:0.0 pactl --server unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native set-sink-mute 0 on"

while True:
    if ir_sensor.motion_detected:
        logging.debug("Motion detected")
        # Reset timer
        timer = time.time() + TIMER_DURATION
        # Turn on display and audio
        subprocess.call("xset dpms force on", shell=True)
        result = subprocess.run(f"DISPLAY=:0.0 pactl --server unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native set-sink-mute '{default_sink}' 0", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        with open("output.log", "a") as f:
            f.write(result.stdout.decode())
            f.write(result.stderr.decode())
            f.write(f"Return code: {result.returncode}\n")
    elif timer and time.time() > timer:
        logging.debug("Timer expired")
        # Turn off display and audio
        subprocess.call("xset dpms force off", shell=True)
        result = subprocess.run(f"DISPLAY=:0.0 pactl --server unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native set-sink-mute '{default_sink}' 1", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        with open("output.log", "a") as f:
            f.write(result.stdout.decode())
            f.write(result.stderr.decode())
            f.write(f"Return code: {result.returncode}\n")
        timer = time.time() + TIMER_DURATION  # Set timer to expire immediately
    time.sleep(1)
```